# Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached in Magento on System->Configuration->Save Config

Tags: php, magento, xdebug

**General infromation:**

**Version:** Magento 1.9.2.4 CE

**Server:** Wampserver 3.0.6

**The problem:**

So the problem is whenever I try (in Magento Admin Panel:**System->Configuration**) to save the current configuration **Save Config** I get an **error** saying:

Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp64\www\magento1924\app\Mage.php on line 412

and

Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp64\www\magento1924\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 125

It doesn't matter which type or which configuration section I try to save, it still gives me the exact same error.

Mage.php line 412:

```
public static function getConfig()
{
    return self::$_config;
}
```

Autoload.php line 125:

```
public function destroy()
{
    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
        $this->_saveCollectedStat();
    }
}
```

**Solutions I've tried:**

1. Cleared/flushed cache - no effect
2. Increased the maximum function nesting level in php.ini, tried with 500, 1000 - no effect

Even though seeing the php.ini it seems like everything regarding to xdebug is turned off:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

I've ran out of ideas and I'm quite stuck with the problem at the moment.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

I tried to comment out the extension itself like this:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
;[xdebug]
;zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.0.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"

;xdebug.remote_enable = off
;xdebug.profiler_enable = off
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
;xdebug.show_local_vars=0
;xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000
```

And now it's giving me:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in C:\wamp64\www\magento1924\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php on line 1225

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Have you tried to disable your all custom extension?

Comment: I disabled both of my custom extensions and still no effect.

Comment: If I'm correct then adding ; in front of the zend_extension prevents the extension to get loaded. This didn't work either. I tried to comment everything out about that xdebug (code above) and still no luck.